# React Native onClick is not firing

Tags: react-native, native-base

Working on React Native application for Android using NativeBase, I'm stuck with a problem. Despite using arrow function, the onClick()-event in my Button component is not firing, and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
import {Button, Header, Icon, Item, Input} from 'native-base';

let text = '';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  onButtonClick = () => {
    text = 'yes';
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header searchBar rounded>
          <Item>
            <Icon name="ios-search" />
            <Input placeholder="Search" />
          </Item>
        </Header>
        <Button onClick={() => this.onButtonClick()}>
          <Text>Search</Text>
        </Button>
        <Text>Is the button clicked? {text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(SearchBar);
```

Can you help me? In all other components I implemented the event functionalities exactly like in the example above, and these are working. What is the problem with the above one?

I also tried the Button from React-Native instead of NativeBase - same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A react component is only updated when a state changes.
Here, your text variable changes, but your react component doesn't know it has to update.

You should use `onPress` instead of `onClick` and do this to trigger a re-render (update a state) :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
import {Button, Header, Icon, Item, Input} from 'native-base';


class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  onButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({text: 'yes'});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header searchBar rounded>
          <Item>
            <Icon name="ios-search" />
            <Input placeholder="Search" />
          </Item>
        </Header>
        <Button onPress={() => this.onButtonClick()}>
          <Text>Search</Text>
        </Button>
        <Text>Is the button clicked? {this.state.text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(SearchBar);
```

Answer (score 2):

it is called "onPress" in react native
refer: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.58/button

Comment: i faced that issue 5 minutes back :)